# Пропал перевод сообщения при попытке задать вопрос анонимным пользователем

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, анонимный-пользователь

Попытаться задать вопрос анонимным пользователем:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Изменил "перевод строки" на "перевод сообщения" из-за того, что уже третий раз захожу сюда чтобы прочитать как из вопроса пропадает символ перевода на новую строку...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть переведённая строка: https://ru.traducir.win/string/11617

Появилась новая, они там кавычки поменяли, видимо, по ошибке: https://ru.traducir.win/string/11838

Предложил тот вариант, что и раньше был:

> Нажимая на кнопку «$submitButtonText$», вы соглашаетесь с нашими
>   $tosLinkStart$пользовательским соглашением$tosLinkEnd$,
>   $privacyLinkStart$политикой конфиденциальности$privacyLinkEnd$ и
>   $cookieLinkStart$политикой о куки$cookieLinkEnd$

Comment: Соглашение с соглашением как-то масло масленно получается...

Comment: @αλεχολυτ пока предложил то, что было. Но всегда можно предложить вариант получше )

Comment: "Я его предложила из того что было. А потом что было, то и утвердила"... :)